# mobile navigation

Tags: mobile, wai-aria

I am creating a tablist for a website, and am looking to modify the experience on a mobile.

I am looking to create a select list for the navigation tab items.

Is is valid to keep arai roles such as role='tab' for option's

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok im thinking that an accordion on mobile may be a better fit.  That way i can use the same aria roles, similar markup and have a better ui on the mobile.

Anyone have anything to add?

EG. 
http://test.cita.illinois.edu/aria/tabpanel/tabpanel2.php